# Can't stop a Coroutine in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to stop waves spawning upon player death but I cant seem to stop the coroutine. I don't really know how to attack this any more because adding if statements and breaks didn't work. How do I call StopCoroutine and have the routine stop? Would I need to introduce new methods and such?

```
void Start () {
    gameOver = false;
    StartCoroutine (SpawnWaves());
}

void Update()
{
    if (gameOver)
    {
        StopCoroutine(SpawnWaves());
    }
  }

IEnumerator SpawnWaves()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject enemy = enemies[Random.Range(0, enemies.Length)];
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition1, spawnRotation1);
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition2, spawnRotation2);
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition3, spawnRotation3);
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition4, spawnRotation4);
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition5, spawnRotation5);
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition6, spawnRotation6);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnWait);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
        enemies[0].GetComponent<EnemyBehviour>().currentHealth *= enemyHealthMultiplier;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work unless gameOver never changes to true.

Comment: public void GameOver()
    {
        gameOverText.text = "Game Over!";
        gameOver = true;
    }  /This is called and it switches gameOver to true. Tested via debug log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to set gameOver to True when the player dies
2. You also need to add logic to change while loop to false to get out of the while loop.

For example set `gameOver = true` when `currentHealth == 0` inside the while loop
and set `while(gameOver == false)`

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem may be that when you call StopCoroutine() you aren't directing it to stop your specific instance of the coroutine. You instead need to store a reference to your coroutine and pass that as the parameter to your Stop.

```
IEnumerator wavecoroutine = SpawnWaves();
StartCoroutine(wavecoroutine);

...

StopCoroutine(wavecoroutine);
```

Comment: Almost. Should be `Coroutine wavecoroutine = StartCoroutine(SpawnWaves());`

Comment: they are interchangeable. StopCoroutine accepts either a string, IEnumerator, or Coroutine

Comment: Huh, so it does. I either didn't notice or forgot. Still, I tend to use the `Coroutine` reference in my own code.

Answer (score 2):

The full fix thanks to @AlexG's guidance

```
void Start () {
    gameOver = false;
    StartCoroutine (SpawnWaves());
}

IEnumerator SpawnWaves()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWait);
    while (gameOver != true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++)
        {
            if(gameOver)break;
            GameObject enemy = enemies[Random.Range(0, enemies.Length)];
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition1, spawnRotation1);
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition2, spawnRotation2);
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition3, spawnRotation3);
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition4, spawnRotation4);
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition5, spawnRotation5);
            Instantiate(enemy, spawnPosition6, spawnRotation6);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnWait);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
        enemies[0].GetComponent<EnemyBehviour>().currentHealth *= eenter code herenemyHealthMultiplier;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ryeMoss actually has the correct answer. You don't need to change the conditions of your while loop, but instead need to make sure you're passing a reference value to the `StopCoroutine` method. You can see in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) that that's exactly what they're doing.

The problem is when `SpawnWaves` is called it returns a new `IEnumerator` which is obviously not what you want when you're trying to stop it, haha.

Just change inside your `Start` method to

```
gameOver = false;
waves = SpawnWaves(); <-- or whatever you want to call it
StartCoroutine(waves); <-- using a reference
```

and then pass `waves` to `StopCoroutine`.

Always read the docs carefully; they're your best friend when learning new libraries, frameworks, etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest correct answer:

```
Coroutine CO_WriteBleDevice = null;
IEnumerator DO_WriteBleDevice()
{
    // something work
    CO_WriteBleDevice = null;
}

void StartWriteBleDevice()
{
    if (CO_WriteBleDevice == null)
        CO_WriteBleDevice = StartCoroutine(DO_WriteBleDevice());
}

void StopWriteBleDevice()
{
    if (CO_WriteBleDevice != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(CO_WriteBleDevice);
        CO_WriteBleDevice = null;
    }
}
```